# Ruby Array Variable Reference Lost During Loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, scope

I am writing a parsing routine in Ruby 2.1 for a spreadsheet.  The code works properly through the first array of pricing data.  Unfortunately, on the fifth loop through datatable, while processing the second set of pricing data, the variable termtable is not set, even though @tmptermtables is modified by the shift method in this statement on line 72: `termtable = @tmptermtables.shift if termtable.empty?` This is possibly a scope problem and I am hoping someone can explain to me why the reference is lost.

Below is a copy of the code.  Thank you in advance for lending me your brain.

```
def sp_parser()
begin

pricing_date = Date.new(2014,2,7)
tz = DateTime.parse(Time.now.to_s).strftime('%z')
expires = DateTime.new(pricing_date.year,pricing_date.mon,pricing_date.mday,17,00,00,tz)

datatable = Array.new
datatable << ["Zone","Business - Low Load Factor",nil,nil,nil,"Business - Medium Load Factor",nil,nil,nil,"Business - High Load Factor",nil,nil,nil]
datatable << [nil,6,9,12,15,6,9,12,15,6,9,12,15]
datatable << [nil,"Daily Pricing",nil,nil,nil,"Daily Pricing",nil,nil,nil,"Daily Pricing",nil,nil,nil]
datatable << ["COAST",6.41,6.55,6.19,6.01,6.07,6.18,5.88,5.74,5.63,5.71,5.48,5.37]
datatable << ["NORTH",6.58,6.74,6.35,6.15,6.02,6.13,5.85,5.68,5.61,5.68,5.47,5.33]
datatable << [nil,3/1/2014,nil,nil,nil,3/1/2014,nil,nil,nil,3/1/2014,nil,nil,nil]
datatable << ["COAST",7.08,6.53,6.20,6.00,6.63,6.17,5.89,5.73,6.06,5.69,5.49,5.36]
datatable << ["NORTH",7.34,6.72,6.36,6.13,6.60,6.10,5.86,5.66,6.06,5.65,5.48,5.31]

loadprofiles = Array.new
termtables = Array.new
pvalue = 0
load_factor_found = false
daily_pricing_found = false
dataset = []


datatable.each_index {|row|
  record = datatable[row]
  termtable = Array.new
  @tmptermtables = Array.new(termtables)
  @tmploadprofiles = Array.new(loadprofiles)

  record.each_index {|col|
    val = record[col]
    ## Build the load profile table
    loadprofiles << "LOW" if val.to_s.downcase.match(/ low/)
    loadprofiles << "MEDIUM" if val.to_s.downcase.match(/medium/)
    loadprofiles << "HIGH" if val.to_s.downcase.match(/high/)
    load_factor_found = true if val.to_s.downcase.match(/load factor/)
    daily_pricing_found = true if val.to_s.downcase.match(/daily pricing/)

    ## Build the term tables for each load profile
    if load_factor_found and !daily_pricing_found
      isinteger = val.is_a? Integer
      if isinteger
        cvalue = val
        if cvalue > pvalue
          termtable << cvalue
          pvalue = cvalue
          termtables << termtable if col == record.length - 1
        else
          unless termtable.empty?
            termtables << termtable
            termtable = []
            termtable << cvalue
            pvalue = cvalue
          end
        end
      else
        cvalue = 0
      end
    end


    if daily_pricing_found
      @start_date = pricing_date if val.to_s.downcase.match(/daily pricing/)
      @start_date = val if val.is_a? Date
      @zone = "CenterPoint" if val.to_s.downcase.match(/coast/)
      @zone = "Oncor" if val.to_s.downcase.match(/north/)

      if val.is_a? Float
        @load = @tmploadprofiles.shift if termtable.empty?

# Here is where it breaks
        termtable = @tmptermtables.shift if termtable.empty?

        term = termtable.shift unless termtable.empty?
        price = (val/100).round(4)
        r = {
            :loaded => Time.now,
            :start => @start_date,
            :load => @load,
            :term => term,
            :zone => @zone,
            :price => price,
            :expiration =>  expires,
            :product => "Fixed"
        }
        dataset << r
      end
    end
  }
}


return dataset
  rescue => err
    puts "\n" + DateTime.parse(Time.now.to_s).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %r") + "  Exception: #{__callee__} in #{__FILE__} generated an error: #{err}\n"
    err
  end
end

x = sp_parser()
```

Comment: `datatable.each_index {|row|
  record = datatable[row]` should be `datatable.each_with_index { |record,row|`

Comment: just a suggestion to improve this, extract each step into a separate method. Really long methods and multi-level if statements are a code smell and make it difficult to modify and debug the code.

Comment: Meagar, thank you for the example of how I may improve the code.

Comment: Regardless of whether the problem is resolved here, you should consider posting your code at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), a Stack Exchange sister site.  There you can ask for suggestions for improving the code generally. (SO is not designed for that.).  There are many regular contributors at CR who would be happy to help you improve your proficiency with Ruby.  I think you'd learn a lot from that.  As you appear to be new at SO, have a look at this [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Cary, thanks for introducing me to CodeReview.  I have posted the code there as you suggested.